Show that the Potential Kernel is half of the Green function
Consider $(X_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$, a simple discrete time random walk on $\mathbb{Z}^2$. We denote $$p_n(x,y) = \mathbb{P}_x(X_n = y),$$
and we define the potential kernel as:
$$a(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} p_n(0,0)-p_n(0,x)$$
Furthermore, define $\tau_0$ be the first hitting time of $X_n$ at $0$, and $L_{\tau_0}(x)$ be the number of visits to $x$ up to time $\tau_0$.
Define the 'Green function':
$$G(x, y)= \mathbb{E}_x[L_{\tau_0}(y)].$$
I have an exercise which is to show that:
$$a(x) = \frac{1}{2}G(x,x).$$
I tried for a long time and I couldn't prove this. I though it might be useful to use the followin fact, which I know and was able to prove:
For any finite domain $D \subset \mathbb{Z}^2$, define Poisson's kernel as $H^D(x,A)=\mathbb{P}_x(X_{\tau_{D^c}} \in A)$, where $\tau_{D^c}$ is the first exit time of the random walk outside of $D$. Further define:
$$G^D(x,y) = \mathbb{E}_x[L_{\tau_{D^c}}(y)].$$
Then, I know that:
$$G^D(x,y) = -a(x-y) + \sum_{z \in \partial D}a(z-y)H^D(x,z).$$
I tried to use the above equality and take a limit as $D \to \mathbb{Z}^2$. I couldn't get this convergence results, does someone know the answer and can please provide some insights regarding the matter?
